# White disclosure indicator

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my app I have a UITableView with a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator. I don't want to change the whole indicator, but I want to make it white instead of gray. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant, you will have to create your own...you can either add it to the content view directly or set the accessoryView property of UITableViewCell, here is a ref [ref](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView)

Comment: So the best way is just to put a white disclosure button image into the accessory view?